# What does inside a strand mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I'm currently trying to get my hands on `boost::asio` strands. Doing so, I keep reading about "invoking strand `post/dispatch` *inside* or *outside* a strand". Somehow I can't figure out how *inside* a strand differs from *through* a strand, and therefore can't grasp the concept of invoking a strand function *outside* the strand at all.

Probably there is just a small piece missing in my puzzle. Can somebody please give an example how calls to a strand can be inside or outside it?

What I think I've understood so far is that posting something *through* a strand would be

```
m_strand.post(myfunctor);
```

or

```
m_strand.wrap(myfunctor);
io_svc.post(myfunctor);
```

Is the latter considered a call to `dispatch` outside the strand (as opposed to the other being a call to `post` inside it)? Is there some relation between the strand's "inside realm" and the threads the strand operates on?

If being inside a strand simply meant to invoke a strand's function, then the `strand` [class's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) would be pointless. It states that `strand::post` can be invoked outside the strand... That's precisely the part I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given strand object `s`, running *outside* `s` implies that [`s.running_in_this_thread()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/running_in_this_thread.html) returns `false`.  This returns `true` if the calling thread is executing a handler that was submitted to the strand via `post()`, `dispatch()`, or `wrap()`.  Otherwise, it returns `false`:

```cpp
io_service.post(handler);              // handler will run outside of strand
strand.post(handler);                  // handler will run inside of strand
strand.dispatch(handler);              // handler will run inside of strand
io_service.post(strand.wrap(handler)); // handler will run inside of strand
```

---

Given:

- a strand object `s`
- a function object `f1` that is added to strand `s` via `s.post()`, or `s.dispatch()` when `s.running_in_this_thread() == false`
- a function object `f2` that is added to strand `s` via `s.post()`, or `s.dispatch()` when `s.running_in_this_thread() == false`

then the strand provides a guarantee of ordering and non-concurrency, such that `f1` and `f2` will not be invoked concurrently.  Furthermore, if the addition of `f1` happens before the addition of `f2`, then `f1` will be invoked before `f2`.

Comment: Switched accepted answer to this one because it focuses more on the original question: what does *inside* a strand mean?

Answer (score 10):

Even I had some trouble in understanding this concept, but became clear once I started working on `libdispatch`. It helped me map things with `asio` better.

Now lets see how to make some sense out of  `strand`. Consider `strand` as a serial queue of `handlers` which needs to be executed.

Now, where does these handlers get executed ? Within the `worker` threads.

Where did these worker threads come from ? From the `io_service` object you passed while creating the strand.
Something like:

```
asio::strand s(io_serv_obj);
```

Now, as you must be knowing, the `io_service::run` can be called by a single thread or multiple threads. The threads calling the `run` method of the `io_serv_obj` are the worker threads for that strand in our case. So, it could be either single threaded or multithreaded.

Coming back to strands, when you `post` a handler, that handler is *always* enqueued in the serial queue which we talked about. The worker threads will pick up the handler from the queue one after the other.

Now, when you do a `dispatch`, asio does some optimization for you:

1. It checks whether you are calling it from inside one of the worker thread or from some other thread (maybe of some other `io_service` instance). When it is called outside the current execution context of the strand, thats when it is called `outside the strand`. So, in the `outside` case, the dispatch will just enqueue the handler like `post` when there are other handlers waiting in the queue or will call it directly when it can guarantee that it will not be called concurrently with any other handler from that queue that may be running in one of the worker threads at that moment.

**UPDATE:**
As noted in the comments section, `inside` means `called within another handler` i.e for eg: I posted a handler `A` and inside that handler, I am doing a `dispatch` of another handler. Now, as would be explained in #2, if there are no other handlers waiting in the strands serial queue, the dispatch handler will be called synchronously. If this condition is not met, that means, the `dispatch` is called from `outside`.

2. Now, if you call `dispatch` from `outside` of the strand i.e not within the current execution context, asio checks its `callstack` to see if any other handler present in its serial queue is running or not. If *not*, then it will directly call that handler synchronously. So, there is no cost of enqueueing the handler (I think no extra allocation will be done as well, not sure though).

Lets see the documentation link now:

> s.dispatch(a) happens-before s.post(b), where the former is performed
>   outside the strand

This means that, if `dispatch` was called from some outside the current `run` OR there are other handlers already enqueued, then it needs to enqueue the handler, it just cannot call it synchronously. Since its a serial queue, `a` will get executed before `b`.

Had there been another call `s.dispatch(c)` along with a and b but before `a` and `b`(in the mentioned order) enqueued, then `c` will get executed before `a` and `b`, but in no way `b` can get executed before `a`.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's really untying a lot of the ugliness. Does that mean that all threads running on the same `io_service` I used to create my `strand` instance are running inside the strand? Or is it only the threads that somehow got in touch with it?

Comment: @TinyT I think all the confusion is coming from the `inside` word :) I would instead say, all those `io_service` threads takes part in executing the handlers provided by the `strand`s serial queue.

Comment: It is - because that's what my question is about. The definition of "when is the execution order guaranteed and when isn't it" with most forum threads (gah!) and boost docs depends on *something* called "inside/outside". **Why does it matter:** If I don't understand that part, I cannot tell if I'm calling inside or out - and if I need to invest in protection mechanisms rather than re-arrangement of invocations when things don't work. So... I'll count that as a "yes". ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TinyT With strands you do not need any locking protection because it guarantees that no handler will run concurrently. The same guarantee will be met even by dispatch as well, the only special case is that if you are calling dispatch you should not be dependent on the order of execution of another handler say `a` or `b`.

Comment: That's the intention. I'm trying to work around a lock that breaks everything. I can't remove it because it's outside my code, but the part of code will be called from several other program points - if I understood correctly, all "inside" the strand (if using it).

Comment: It actually doesnt matter if you use `post` for all handlers. "inside" means from a thread which is calling the io_service::run of the io_service instance which you passed to the strand. To make it easy, just use `post` and check if it meets your requirements.

Comment: While it does not matter if one only uses `post()`, for clarification, not all threads executing `io_service::run()` are _inside_ the strand.  [`strand::running_in_this_thread()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/running_in_this_thread.html) can be used to determine if the strand is running in the current thread.  Also, I believe some of the details about `dispatch()` are incorrect, as `dispatch()` respects both the ordering and non-concurrency guarantees (e.g. a handler may be queued even if no strand handlers are currently running).

Comment: @TannerSansbury Yes `dispatch` respects `non-concurrency` guarantee, I don't see written otherwise in my answer. For `ordering` I meant handler execution ordering. Since handlers can be posted from multiple threads there in no guarantee that a post from thread-1 will happen before a post from thread-2.

Comment: @Arunmu Perhaps I am misunderstanding.  The answer currently implies that any thread running the `io_service` is _inside_ the strand, and that `dispatch()` from anyone of these threads will synchronously invoke a handler if Asio does not detect that any other handler that was submitted to the strand is _running_.   I believe that these details are incorrect as it would violate the ordering guarantee.  Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56f822ddd6562c2c) that demonstrates `dispatch()` not immediately executing a handler while no other strand handlers are running.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Yes, you are correct, I had misunderstood the `callstack` part in the asio source. It wont get executed if there are handlers waiting in the queue.

Comment: @Arunmu The details on `dispatch()` still seem incorrect to me.  If [`strand::running_in_this_thread()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/running_in_this_thread.html) returns `true`, then the caller is inside the strand; otherwise it is outside.  `dispatch()` will immediately execute the new handler if either `strand::running_in_this_thread()` returns `true`, or `strand::running_in_this_thread()` returns `false` and the caller is running the `io_service` and the order of handler invocation specified by strand can be met.

Comment: @TannerSansbury I really thought that is what I wrote, but my english gets screwed up sometimes. I really should check this in detail.